# Empty a ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a simple Windows form containing among other components, a `ListView` object named `list`. On the form, a button enables me to empty the list on click with `list.Items.Clear()`. This works fine.

Now I have a separate class `Test`, whose method `update()` is called on some events external to the form. At construction of the form, I pass a reference to the list using the `SetList` method. In debug mode, `update()` is called on the events that I trigger, and its content executed, but my list isn't cleared.

Why is this? The reference is properly set, I checked.

```
class Test
{
   private ListView list;

   public void setList(ListView list)
   {
      this.list = list;
   }

   public void update()
   {
      this.list.Items.Clear();
   }
}
```

when I look closer at my list being modified by putting breakpoints in update(), list is cleaned and stays cleaned. It really seems like it is another list being modified, but I have only one and never do any new on it... ????

Comment: If items bound via data source try out `list.DataSource = null; list.DataBind();`

Comment: my guess would be that it isn't. I always add through the method this.list.Items.Add

Comment: The 95% odds with code like this is that you are clearing the listview of another form instance, one that isn't visible because you created it with new instead of using the visible form instance.

Comment: Try out setting breakpoint on the next line after the `this.list.Items.Clear();` and see in debugger whether Items cleared, perhaps some external code adding items, who know what happens in your application...

Comment: Is it cleared but then immediately populated again?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the Clear() line and inspect the contents of list.Items before the line is executed. If it's empty, you're looking at the wrong list. (BTW, you could just pass list.Items to the Test class, instead of list itself.)

Comment: Please post the code where you use this class

Comment: hans, can you elaborate on your answer ? I don't get your point but feel there is something there

Comment: when I look closer at my list being modified, it is cleaned and stays cleaned, it really seems like it is another list ... ????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the below modified `update` method:

```
   public void update()
   {
      this.list.Items.Clear();
      this.list.Update(); // In case there is databinding
      this.list.Refresh(); // Redraw items
   }
```

If this doesn't work, it is evident that you're modifying another instance of the `list` object. In this case, temporarily modify the declaration of the object like below and see if changes anything. If it does, you'll need to review your code to make sure that you're clearing the right instance of the list:

```
private static ListView list;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am not using data bindings, but rather add items explicitly in a loop using Add().  It appeared to me that `ListView.Clear()` and `ListView.Items.Clear()` weren't working.

Turns out...the ListView *was* actually being cleared, but I hadn't been clearing the input list, so I was effectively clearing and then re-populating the ListView with the previously-cleared items.

Sometimes it's the simplest things...D'OH!